# It is Possible to remove last words of current post title and echo the result?

Tags: php, wordpress

It is possible to remove one or two last words of current post title and echo the result?

Example:

> This is me not you

I want delete two last words "not you"

So the result is:

> This is me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, any changes to a theme will reside within a WordPress child theme.

Broadly speaking, this should do it:

```
 $post_title = get_the_title();
 $post_title_output = explode( " ", $post_title );
 array_splice( $post_title_output, -2 );
 echo implode( " ", $post_title_output );
```

Comment: Lovely solution!

Comment: Thanks, though looking at the [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51897916/4034148) I think that is better practice/more specific vs my more generic overview.

Comment: Potentially... I'd be interested on benchmarks of the two, nice to see a WP specific solution those yours is nice too!

Comment: Thanks, it work and more specific for expand the code with other.

Answer (score 1):

the_title is a filter applied to the post title retrieved from the database, prior to printing on the screen. In some cases (such as when the_title is used), the title can be suppressed by returning a false value (e.g. NULL, FALSE or the empty string) from the filter function.

Add following code in function.php

```
    function limit_post_title($title,$id=null) {
$totalwords=str_word_count($title);
    $limit=$totalwords-2;
          if (str_word_count($title, 0) > $limit) {
              $words = str_word_count($title, 2);
              $pos = array_keys($words);
              $title = substr($title, 0, $pos[$limit]) . '...';
          }
          return $title;
        }
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'limit_post_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This good too, however it little bit complicated for me. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need to do anything if you apply above code use same filter.